# Scale Animation with only one letter?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-animation

in my activity is one word "Ecl pse" and a button. After I click on the button I want the letter "i" to appear big and then getting smaller until it is as big as the the other letters of the word Ecl pse. Momentarily the whole word Eclipse is influenced by the scale Animation. So after I clicked on the button the whole word Eclipse appears bigger and getting smaller. But I only want the letter "i" scale animated. How does that work?

```
public Button btn;
public TextView tw;
Animation a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pagetwo);



    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnKlick);
    tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvhallo);
    a= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Ecl pse");  

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String text = tw.getText().toString();
    int n = 3; 
    String newText = text.substring(0, n) + "i" + text.substring(n + 1);

    tw.setText(newText);
    tw.startAnimation(a);
```

Comment: Why not just use a separate textview for the "i"?

Comment: It is difficult to put the i between Ecl and pse, that it is in the same distance like the other letters are?! I don't know how that works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) (text with markup) with a [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) to update the relative size of the part you want over time. For example:

```
ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
animator.setDuration(4000);
animator.setObjectValues("Ecl pse", "Eclipse");

animator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator<CharSequence>()
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence evaluate(float fraction, CharSequence startValue, CharSequence endValue)
    {
        float relativeSize = 4 - 3 * fraction;
        Spannable span = new SpannableString("Eclipse");
        span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(relativeSize), 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return span;
    }
});

animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
    {
        textView.setText((CharSequence)animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});

animator.start();
```

This will show an "i" 4 times as large as the surrounding text, then make it smaller until it's the same size as the rest. You can customize duration, interpolator, &c to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: thx, but with that code it's not only that the I is bigger and gets smaller, but also the position of the whole word Ecl pse changes. It goes down and then Comes back in the origin Position?!

Comment: That depends on the TextView's textAlignment and its height value in LayoutParams (probably WRAP_CONTENT -- as the text gets larger, so does the View size). You should be able to fix it by changing those parameters.

Comment: ok, but is it not possible to use my code and differ it only a Little bit?

Comment: I don't think so. Scale animations apply to whole views.

Comment: Is it possible to give the "i" another Color?

Comment: @user3341325 Yes, you can do a lot of things with Spannables. See [ForegroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html)

Comment: ok, thx, but I don't get the solution for my first Problem. That for a while the position of the whole word "Ecl pse" changes with your code. How can I change the parameters in LayoutParams? I defined the height of the word "Ecl pse" only in the XML-file?!

Comment: Thank You Very Much for your help! I only have one little Problem. I created the Color orange in R.color.orange. But if I use (R.color.orange) in the code instead of (Color.GREEN)  it gets grey?! Could you help me please?

Comment: @user3341325 You need to use `getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)` (the actual color _value_) instead of `R.color.orange` (the color _id_).

Comment: I tried it like that `span.setSpan (new ForegroundColorSpan(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)),3, 4, 0);` but he tells me that the method getResources is undefined for the CharSequence

Comment: @user3341325 Use `Activity_Class_Name.this`.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that for animating the foreground or background color I would use the same technique but of course with a different type on the TypeEvaluator?